# 'Cannot allocate memory' when submit Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I got an error when try to submit a Spark Job to yarn.

But I can't understand which JVM throwed this error.

How can I avoid this error?

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006bff80000, 3579314176, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 3579314176 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/hs_err_pid6272.log
[DBUG]: AppID NOT FOUND 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/step.py", line 119, in act
    self.actionclass.run(step = self)
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/action/base.py", line 60, in run
    cls.__run__(step)
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/action/sparkjobsubmit.py", line 43, in __run__
    handler.submit_job(step.template, step.args['submit_user'])
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/handler/SparkBaseHandler.py", line 115, in submit_job
    raise RuntimeError(msg_f)
RuntimeError: <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x5a929e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/engine/koala.py", line 34, in process
    step.act()
  File "/opt/meituan/warehouse/ETL/sqlweaver/../sqlweaver/step.py", line 128, in act
    raise e
RuntimeError: <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x5a929e0>
Fail in Action Step(SparkJobSubmit)
"
```